# how to browse a folder named '-' in linux machine

Tags: linux, command

I have created a directory named -

---

[root@server50 public_html]#
mkdir -

[root@server50 public_html]# ls -al

drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 2011-03-16 02:22 -

---

How can I enter the directory using 'cd' command.

Answer (score 10):

You can prepend the current directory:

```
cd ./-
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up the man page for `cd` and you see that a command-line argument consisting of a single hyphen is treated as a $OLDPWD variable. To prevent this from happening, you simply need to replace the "single hyphen" with more information from its path: Some ways to do this are:

```
cd /full/path/to/-
cd ./-
cd ././-
```

Anything so that a single hyphen "-" by itself does not appear on the command line, otherwise it will be interpreted as the old-working-directory